# Is it possible to cast quickfix messages into specific classes in order to have intellisense guide?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I´m pretty new in quickfix, but according to [official doc](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/sending_messages.html), even in the case you are typing (in the way of assigning a type) the message you want to send. You have to know in advance which are the available fields. I was expecting to find something more programming friendly. Creating a new OrderCancelRequest, would create an instance where you have a pack of acknowledged variables-properties and IDE would help you to know what field must be provided.

In fact
Type Safe Messages And Fields

```
void sendOrderCancelRequest()
{
  FIX41::OrderCancelRequest message(
    FIX::OrigClOrdID("123"),
    FIX::ClOrdID("321"),
    FIX::Symbol("LNUX"),
    FIX::Side(FIX::Side_BUY));

  message.set(FIX::Text("Cancel My Order!"));

  FIX::Session::sendToTarget(message, SenderCompID("TW"), TargetCompID("TARGET"));
}
```

and Type Safe Field Only

```
void sendOrderCancelRequest()
{
  FIX::Message message;
  FIX::Header header& = message.getHeader();

  header.setField(FIX::BeginString("FIX.4.2"));
  header.setField(FIX::SenderCompID(TW));
  header.setField(FIX::TargetCompID("TARGET"));
  header.setField(FIX::MsgType(FIX::MsgType_OrderCancelRequest));
  message.setField(FIX::OrigClOrdID("123"));
  message.setField(FIX::ClOrdID("321"));
  message.setField(FIX::Symbol("LNUX"));
  message.setField(FIX::Side(FIX::Side_BUY));
  message.setField(FIX::Text("Cancel My Order!"));

  FIX::Session::sendToTarget(message);
}
```

Shows not too much difference. In both cases you have to know which are valid tags to be provided. Maybe, in the second example, the compiler allows you to provide wrong fields, not sure. But at the end, you have to consult which are the available fields to kind of message you want to send (it´s similar to receive, cracking does not help too much, in onMessage you have to know which are the available fields)

So, summarizing. Is it possible to find any smarter way to work with quickfix in order to have more help from the IDE-context? I was thinking about a kind of direct message-class maping.

Thanks a lot for your help. Maybe it´s due to I´m new with quickfix, but I have the feeling that using it oblies you to know messages available fields at the end.

Comment: There is a lot of broker by broker variety on which fields are expected in a given message that it is difficult to assume a given field structure for a given message type. I don't think you'll be able to rely heavily on intellisense to tell you which fields you can add to a message.

Comment: I was expecting at least a clue. I mean,  maybe some fields are not mandatory and intellisensse suggestes you them, but at least being able to roll over possible tags. Programming a "client" from scratch if you are looking for a MVP, does not look to different than using quickfix. If at the end I have to program all message types iteration, create proper classes with required info.... It's true quickfix can help a lot checking that messages themselves follow specific templates, but using these messages' contain/info, it's similar to programming from scracth :(

Comment: I just noticed you are setting the header and you don't need to do that. Quickfix will add it when you do `sendToTarget(..)`. There is a lot more complexity in FIX (ex: managing sessions) than just constructing messages and `quickfix` will help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Paul, but in fact that is not my code. It's a copy paste of official quickfix documentation to send messages.. I already knew header was automatically filled, but thanks for the reminder.